How to write doc comments for enum variants with multiple data holders in Rust?
I have the following enum
pub enum Force {
    Elastic(f64, f64),
    Damping(f64),
    Gravitational,
    Sticky(f64, f64, f64, f64),
}

and I want to document what each parameter from each variant means. I have been looking in the Rust book, the Rustdoc book, etc. but cannot find a specific section about this. For example:
/// Represents a force.
pub enum Force {
    /// The force by an ideal spring, parameters are (k,d0).
    Elastic(f64, f64),
    /// The force by a linear damping, the parameter is the proportionality factor between velocity and force.
    Damping(f64),
    /// Gravitational force given by Newton's formula.
    Gravitational,
    /// A sticky force, parameters are (d_well, d_max, F_sticky, F_repuls).
    Sticky(f64, f64, f64, f64),
}

Though this accomplishes the goal, I want to know what the standard is

That is good, I did not know that there were "struct variants". If you would want to write a small comment explaining what each of them is, e.g. d_well: The distance at which the lowest potential is found. how would you do it? Or is there no standard for this?

The idiomatic way would be to use descriptive code instead of unnamed fields of tuple variants.
So either use struct variants:
pub enum Force {
    /// A sticky force
    Sticky {
        /// The distance at which the lowest potential is found.
        d_well: f64,
    },
}

or separate structs:
pub enum Force {
    /// A sticky force
    Sticky(Sticky),
}
pub struct Sticky {
    /// The distance at which the lowest potential is found.
    pub d_well: f64,
}

The latter has the advantage that you can talk about Sticky and its fields without having to talk about a whole Force object.
Both immediatly turn your comments into code that can't go out of sync. And as an added bonus, you can freely reoder fields where you create an instance and LSPs can assist you easily.
